# "Lost connection to MySQL server during query" in Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I am having a weird, recurring but not constant, error where I get "2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query'". These are the premises:

- a Python app runs around 15-20minutes every hour and then stops (hourly scheduled by cron)
- the app is on a GCE n1-highcpu-2 instance, the db is on a D1 with a per package pricing plan and the following mysql flags

> ```
> max_allowed_packet    1073741824
> slow_query_log    on
> log_output    TABLE
> log_queries_not_using_indexes on
> ```

- the database is accessed only by this app and this app only so the usage is the same, around 20 consecutive minutes per hour and then nothing at all for the other 40 minutes
- the first query it does is

> ```
> SELECT users.user_id, users.access_token, users.access_token_secret, users.screen_name, metadata.last_id
> FROM users
> LEFT OUTER JOIN metadata ON users.user_id = metadata.user_id
> WHERE users.enabled = 1
> ```

- the above query joins two tables that are each around 700 lines longs and do not have indexes
- after this query (which takes 0.2 seconds when it runs without problems) the app starts without any issues

Looking at the logs I see that each time this error presents itself the interval between the start of the query and the error is 15 minutes.

I've also enabled the slow query log and those query are registered like this:

```
    start_time: 2014-10-27 13:19:04
    query_time: 00:00:00
     lock_time: 00:00:00
     rows_sent: 760
 rows_examined: 1514
            db: foobar
last_insert_id: 0
     insert_id: 0
     server_id: 1234567
      sql_text: ...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If your connection is idle for the 15 minute gap the you are probably seeing GCE disconnect your idle TCP connection, as described at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#communicatewithinternet. Try the workaround that page suggests:

```
sudo /sbin/sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=60 net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl=60 net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes=5
```

(You may need to put this configuration into /etc/sysctl.conf to make it permanent)

Comment: Thanks, I added that and I don't seem to experience anymore the connection lost error at startup but sometimes it does happen during writes and I am quite sure there's no idle connection there. I will have to investigate further but I might be also hitting the limit of simultaneous connections indicated here https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#sizeqps

Comment: Connection limits are only enforced when connections are started.  Other possible causes of connections dropping during query are documented at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-lost-connection.html. If this is very infrequent it may also be due to system-initiated restarts of your Cloud SQL instance.